# Problems in motion

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors

[image]

Above is a homework problem I'm trying to solve. Since the problem asks for a new coordinate for A, I put it as $\binom{x}{y}$. Then after two seconds, it must have moved $\binom{-8}{-4}$. Meanwhile, B's position stays the same, and it also moves for $2$ seconds. So $\binom{1}{3} + \binom{8}{-2}$  results in $\binom{9}{1}$, where A with the new initial point should end up as well. Then shouldn't $\binom{x}{y}$ be $\binom{17}{5}$? The answer states it is $\binom{31/3}{23/3}$, but I don't understand what is wrong with my method...

### Update:

Thanks to everyone who affirmed that my method was not in error. However, then another problem arises - the brief solution provided in the answer seems to make sense to me as well, albeit resulting in a different answer!

Using parametric equations, for A they have come up with a rectangular equation $x=-1+2y$ and for B they came up with $x=13-4y$. Then equating the two and substituting the resulting y value into one of the rectangular equations, they get that the intersection point is at $x=11/3$ and $y=7/3$. Then setting A's initial point as $\binom{x}{y}$, they use $\binom{x}{y} = \binom{11/3}{7/3}+2\binom{4}{2}$. Is their method wrong then? How?

Comment: The "answers at the back of the book" are frequently wrong.

Comment: I agree! Your working seems correct and so does your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are making the assumption, which I find reasonable, that changing the original position of A does not change its velocity.  Once you make that assumption your calculation is fine.  I don't see an easy way to get the book answer.

Added:  They have found the correct lines that A and B travel on.  The point $(11/3,7/3)$ is the intersection point of those lines, but they do not reach the point at the same time.  A gets there at $t=5/6$ and B at $t=2/3$.  They then move A's start so it hits that intersection point at $t=2$, but that fails to get B to the same point at $t=2$.  They have to move B to a start point along the same line to arrive at $t=2$, but the problem does not allow that.

Comment: thanks for the affirmation, but do you mind reading the update? I'm confused because the solution seems to make sense to me as well.